# Why does my Promise fall with error?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm testing how ES6 promises handle errors. I think that Promises never throw errors, but instead they rejects with proper errors.

I can not understand why this promise

```
var request = require("request"); // popular npm library
new Promise((resolve) => {
  request("http://ya.ru", (err, res, body) => {
    sdcsdcsdc.sdcsdcsdc.sdcsdcsdc.sdcsdcsdc
  });
})
```

falls with error (and breaks my script):

```
Promise { <pending> }
ReferenceError: sdcsdcsdc is not defined
    at Request._callback (repl:1:74)
    ...
```

, but this one

```
new Promise((resolve) => { sdcsdcsdc.sdcsdcsdc.sdcsdcsdc.sdcsdcsdc })
```

happily rejects without breaking my script:

```
Promise { <rejected> [ReferenceError: sdcsdcsdc is not defined] }
```

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your scripts before asking why they fail.

Comment: There is no "syntax errors". I used "undefined" vars to test how it will work. And it works differently for this two promises

Comment: Then you should explain that circumstance in an introductory paragraph. Too many people post botched code.

Comment: Also, you should include the `request()` function definition.

Comment: Thanks. Added more details

Comment: In short: `request(…, (…)=>{…})` is not a promise callback. See that duplicate for details.